# a - b > 0 algebra correction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simple Algebra

$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{5} > 0$

$\frac{1}{2} > \frac{1}{5}$

$5 >2$

Looks correct, but where am I wrong in this,

$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{5} > 0$

$-\frac{1}{5} > -\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{1}{5} > \frac{1}{2}$

$ 2 > 5$

Comment: when you multiply both sides by $-1$, the inequality direction changes

Comment: got it, thanks Alex :)

Answer (score 2):

$-1>-2$, but does that imply that $1>2$? In general, if $a<b$ then $-a>-b$.

Answer (score 1):

$-\frac{1}{5} > -\frac{1}{2}$ implies that 1/2>1/5 not the other way around